# Alternative to rewarding the users for facebook share in iOS app? Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I was planning to allow the user to access this one feature within my app when he/she shares my app link on his/her facebook(a.k.a. rewarding the user for facebook sharing)

But I am guessing.. that it will be rejected if I do such thing,
according to this article.

```
http://www.theverge.com/2014/6/10/5796090/apple-rejecting-apps-that-reward-social-sharing
```

Is there any alternative way to effectively promote my app within the users' society?

Comment: Make it awesome so people want to share it

Comment: That is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy. I suggest reading it

Answer (score 0):

The article you posted is dated 2014/6/10, is it still relevant?

Comment: I guess that is a good question. Crossy Roads made $6.000.000 with this kind of advertising - rewarding players with ingame coins for watching advertising videos of other games not owned by the crossy road developers.